# object object object has no method slides/autocomplete'

Tags: jquery

My site has been working completely fine for months but now suddenly no longer.
Chrome provides me these errors:

object object object has no method autocomplete' //When ajax search is enabled

object object object has no method slides' //When ajax search is denable

I tried reading other people's questions with the same problem. But seems like in most cases, it was caused by several loadings of the jquery lib - which ain't in my case.

My code is sorta long, so here is the link:
http://tinyurl.com/d2cn6ng

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, jQuery *is* loaded twice in this case:

Line 34:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Line 765:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script><script src="jqueryui.js"></script><script src="dle_js.js"></script>
```

Different versions - the second is jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: Ahhh..... you are right. Didn't check in the bottom. Thank you. Now just gotta find out which module add this.